# Is there a way to install app exchange packages programmatically?

Tags: apex, trigger

I noticed that there is a way to [install managed packages via the metadata API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_api_introduction.htm). Is there a way to install app exchange packages programmatically via an API?

For more context, we want the ability to deploy Apex trigger code to our end customer. We first ask users to connect via Salesforce [OAuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) to our product. We were thinking of publishing an app exchange package and using the credentials to programmatically install it. I am open to ideas on how else we can deploy Apex trigger code programmatically if there are better ways.

Answer (score 6):

You can perform package installations programmatically by constructing a Metadata API deployment payload that includes an `InstalledPackage` component, as shown in the link you shared. Note that managed packages and AppExchange packages are, barring some edge-case subtleties, the same thing.

However, it's easier to use the [Tooling API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_packageinstallrequest.htm), by creating a `PackageInstallRequest` object. This requires only an HTTP POST, although the actual installation is asynchronous and you'll have to make additional calls to monitor its progress (via the `Status` field on the created record).

In any case, you **must not install a package without explicit approval and full understanding from the administrator**. Doing so has significant implications and risks for the end user. Performing a package install without explicit approval from the administrator would be considered malware by most Salesforce users.

Your product will have to go through Salesforce Security Review to be listed on the AppExchange. Expect to answer detailed questions about how you're safeguarding customers' orgs.

Comment: I believe ( correct me if I'm wrong) that using `InstalledPackage` will deploy the package for All Users which might not be what you want.

Comment: @cropredy That is correct - there is an undocumented `securityType` element you can include to change that behavior. It's actually documented for `PackageInstallRequest`.

Comment: are all those elements in `PackageInstallRequest` also available as undocumented in `InstalledPackage`?

Comment: They are _not_. And the available security types do not match between the two (`PackageInstallRequest` doesn't support the type `PUSH`).

Answer (score 0):

See this example using the Sfdx CLI in a shell script to setup an org and install packages.
https://github.com/forcedotcom/WorkDotCom-Partners/blob/master/orgInit.sh